# Echo Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to output an array. I get the result but the mysql code too.

The code is:

```
$dorsal = $DB->select_associative_data("atleta_kit", "dorsal", "WHERE id_atleta = '".$Team[0]['atleta_id_atleta']."'");
```

And i'm echoing with

```
 <td height="50px" class="titletable3" align="center"><?php var_dump($dorsal); ?></td>
```

I'm echoing a list of numbers, and by example one of the showed rows is

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["dorsal"]=> string(4) "1195" } }
```

I only want the 1195. How can i get it?

Comment: Why haven't you tried to google for "php how to access array element" first?

Comment: `echo $dorsal[0]['dorsal'];`

Comment: I suggest print_r($dorsal) so that you can get a feel for your array first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$DB` class is returning an array of rows, you may only have 1 row but it's still an array.

```
echo $dorsal[0]["dorsal"];
```

Would esentially do it - we're taking the first row (#0) then the value of "dorsal".

This isn't the best way to do it though, you should ideally check your results exist first and that there were no DB errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is grab it: `echo $dorsal[0]['dorsal']`